# Problema com Fontes no React Native

Tags: react, react-native

Estou com um problema de load com o react native, já instalei ambas as fontes para meu projeto e estava dando tudo certo até que eu parei de trabalhar por um tempo por causa de outro erro. Quando voltei para tentar resolve-lo essas duas mensagens apareceram. Já tentei resolve-las baixando novamente com o comando *npm install* e não mudou. Alguém poderia/saberia me ajudar?
Segue os erros:

```
fontFamily "Ubuntu_700Bold" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
  node_modules\expo\node_modules\expo-font\build\Font.js:29:16 in processFontFamily
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3683:38 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3694:8 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4109:29 in createInstance
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15835:12 in completeWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19409:28 in completeUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19380:30 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
  [native code]:null in renderRoot
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
  [native code]:null in runRootCallback
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11484:17 in dispatchAction
  [native code]:null in dispatchAction
  node_modules\@expo-google-fonts\ubuntu\useFonts.js:20:4 in useEffect$argument_0
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
  [native code]:null in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue






fontFamily "Roboto_400Regular" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
  node_modules\expo\node_modules\expo-font\build\Font.js:29:16 in processFontFamily
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3683:38 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3694:8 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4109:29 in createInstance
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15835:12 in completeWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19409:28 in completeUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19380:30 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
  [native code]:null in renderRoot
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
  [native code]:null in runRootCallback
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11484:17 in dispatchAction
  [native code]:null in dispatchAction
  node_modules\@expo-google-fonts\ubuntu\useFonts.js:20:4 in useEffect$argument_0
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
  [native code]:null in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
ERROR
17:13
fontFamily "Roboto_500Medium" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
  node_modules\expo\node_modules\expo-font\build\Font.js:29:16 in processFontFamily
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3683:38 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3694:8 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4109:29 in createInstance
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15835:12 in completeWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19409:28 in completeUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19380:30 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
  [native code]:null in renderRoot
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
  [native code]:null in runRootCallback
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11484:17 in dispatchAction
  [native code]:null in dispatchAction
  node_modules\@expo-google-fonts\ubuntu\useFonts.js:20:4 in useEffect$argument_0
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
  [native code]:null in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

```
ERROR
17:13
fontFamily "feather" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
  node_modules\expo\node_modules\expo-font\build\Font.js:29:16 in processFontFamily
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3683:38 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3557:6 in addNestedProperty
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3694:8 in diffProperties
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4109:29 in createInstance
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15835:12 in completeWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19409:28 in completeUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19380:30 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
  [native code]:null in renderRoot
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
  [native code]:null in runRootCallback
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7799:17 in classComponentUpdater.enqueueSetState
  node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:325:31 in Component.prototype.setState
  node_modules\@expo\vector-icons\build\createIconSet.js:23:51 in Icon#componentDidMount
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:145:19 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
  [native code]:null in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

segue o código do App:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

import { Roboto_400Regular, Roboto_500Medium } from '@expo-google-fonts/roboto';
import { Ubuntu_700Bold, useFonts } from '@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu';

import Routes from './routes';

export default function App () {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Roboto_400Regular,
    Roboto_500Medium,
    Ubuntu_700Bold
  });

  if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />
  }
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle = "dark-content" backgroundColor = "transparent" translucent/>
      <Routes />
    </>
  )
}
```

segue o código da primeira view index Home:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Feather as Icon } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text, ImageBackground, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { RectButton } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import Select from './Select';

interface Dados {
  uf: string,
  city: string
}
const Home = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  function handleNavigationToPoints() {
    const uf = String(AsyncStorage.getItem('uf'));
    const city = String(AsyncStorage.getItem('city'));
    const dados: Dados = {uf, city}

    navigation.navigate('Points', dados);
  }
  return (
    <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/home-background.png')}
      style={styles.container}
      imageStyle={{ width: 274, height: 368 }}>
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <Image source={require('../../assets/logo.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          Seu marketplace de coleta de resíduos
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.description}>
          Ajudamos pessoas a encontrarem pontos de coleta
          de forma eficiente.
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Select />
        <RectButton style={styles.button}
          onPress={handleNavigationToPoints}>
          <View style={styles.buttonIcon}>
            <Text>
              <Icon name="arrow-right"
                color="#FFF" size={24} />
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Entrar</Text>
        </RectButton>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 32,
  },

  main: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  title: {
    color: '#322153',
    fontSize: 32,
    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu_700Bold',
    maxWidth: 260,
    marginTop: 64,
  },

  description: {
    color: '#6C6C80',
    fontSize: 16,
    marginTop: 16,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular',
    maxWidth: 260,
    lineHeight: 24,
  },

  footer: {},

  input: {
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginBottom: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
    fontSize: 16,
  },

  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#34CB79',
    height: 60,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 24,
  },

  buttonIcon: {
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  buttonText: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    fontFamily: 'Roboto_500Medium',
    fontSize: 16,
  }
});
export default Home;
```

Segue o código do package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~8.1.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-emoji": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.23",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.61.17",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Como está o package.json?

Comment: Acabei de adicionar na publicação ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente os comandos:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -f package-lock.json && rm -f yarn.lock && npm cache verify && npm install && expo r -c
```

Executei os comandos indicados para limpar o cache, mas sem sucesso.

Na sequência:

- Altere no arquivo package.json a versão do expo para `36.0.1` e
  execute o `npm install`.
- Altere novamente a versão do expo para a anterior, `37.0.3` e execute `npm install`.

Este último passo resolveu.

Fonte: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6489

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar. :D

Answer (score -1):

Para mim, bastou apenas executar o comando:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -f package-lock.json && rm -f yarn.lock && npm cache verify && npm install && expo r -c
```